# Popup closed error by react google login package

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authorization

Still, I didn't figure out the Issue!! Here is the version of the plugin `"react-google-login": "^5.1.25",`

> Error "popup_closed_by_user

**Here is my Auth.js**

```js
<GoogleLogin
            clientId="bogudpo170lps7p06hhp3ce26rnao2sn.apps.googleusercontent.com"
            render={(renderProps) => (
              <Button
                className={classes.googleButton}
                color="primary"
                fullWidth
                onClick={renderProps.onClick}
                startIcon={<Icon />}
                disabled={renderProps.disabled}
                variant="contained"
              >
                Google Sign In
              </Button>
            )}
            onSuccess={googleSuccess}
            onFailure={googleFailure}
            cookiePolicy="single_host_origin"
            ux_mode={"popup"}
          />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [@react-oauth/google](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-oauth/google) it uses the new google service identity SDK, maybe it will work for you.

Comment: I will try to implement it!